# Merge two objects to obtain another object with the same structure of the first object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need help with some data structure.

I have these objects:

```
const infos = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient' },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue' },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence' },
}

const datum = { id: 0, columnA: 5, columnB: 100, columnC: 33 }
```

I want another object (`infosWithValues`) like this:

```
const infosWithValues = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient', value: 5 },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue', value: 100 },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence', value: 33 },
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
const infosWithValues = [
  ...Object.entries(infos).map(([columnName, info]) => ({
    [columnName]: { ...info, value: datum[columnName] },
  })),
]
```

But I get:

```
[
  { columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient', value: 5 } },
  { columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue', value: 100 } },
  { columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence', value: 33 } },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, what you need is `reduce` instead of `map`.

```js
const infos = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient' },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue' },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence' },
}

const datum = { id: 0, columnA: 5, columnB: 100, columnC: 33 }

const infosWithValues = Object.entries(infos).reduce((obj,[columnName, info]) => {
    obj[columnName] = { ...info, value: datum[columnName] };
    return obj;
 }, {})

console.log(infosWithValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate object back from entries.

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(infos).map(([key, value]) => [key, { ...value,
  value: datum[key]
}]))
```

```js
const infos = {
  columnA: {
    color: 'red',
    name: 'Column Ancient'
  },
  columnB: {
    color: 'yellow',
    name: 'Column Blue'
  },
  columnC: {
    color: 'green',
    name: 'Column Consequence'
  },
}

const datum = {
  id: 0,
  columnA: 5,
  columnB: 100,
  columnC: 33
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(infos).map(([key, value]) => [key, { ...value,
  value: datum[key]
}]))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

I rather do it in two lines (first to copy `infos` and second to update the values) because it makes the code easier to read:

```js
const infos = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient' },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue' },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence' },
}

const datum = { id: 0, columnA: 5, columnB: 100, columnC: 33 }

// logic starts here!
infosWithValues = { ...infos }; // copy
Object.keys(infosWithValues)
      .forEach(k => infosWithValues[k].value = datum[k]); // update the values

console.log(infosWithValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, an easy way to get your desired result would be to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) your array of objects in a call to `Object.assign()` like so:

```js
const infos = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient' },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue' },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence' },
};

const datum = { id: 0, columnA: 5, columnB: 100, columnC: 33 };
const infosWithValues = Object.assign({}, 
  ...Object.entries(infos).map(([columnName, info]) => ({
    [columnName]: { ...info, value: datum[columnName] },
  })),
);

console.log(infosWithValues);
```

Or, you could use the newer [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method instead which takes an array of `[[key, value], ...]` pairs and builds an object from that array:

```js
const infos = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient' },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue' },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence' },
};

const datum = { id: 0, columnA: 5, columnB: 100, columnC: 33 };
const infosWithValues = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(infos).map(([columnName, info]) => 
    [columnName, { ...info, value: datum[columnName] }]
  )
);

console.log(infosWithValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const infos = {
  columnA: {color: 'red', name: 'Column Ancient' },
  columnB: {color: 'yellow', name: 'Column Blue' },
  columnC: {color: 'green', name: 'Column Consequence' },
}

const datum = { id: 0, columnA: 5, columnB: 100, columnC: 33 }

const infosWithValues = Object.assign({}, infos);

Object.keys(datum).forEach(key => {
  if (infosWithValues[key]) infosWithValues[key].value = datum[key];
});

console.log(infosWithValues);
```